# Layer 2 header is not added by OS (Linux) when using boost::asio::generic::raw_protocol::socket

Tags: c++, linux, boost-asio, raw-sockets

I am using `boost::asio::generic::raw_protocol::socket` to open a socket of family `PF_PACKET` and type `SOCK_DGRAM`.

In my header file:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
MyClass(/*parameters*/);
typedef boost::asio::generic::raw_protocol raw_protocol_t;
typedef boost::asio::generic::basic_endpoint<raw_protocol_t> raw_endpoint_t;

void SetDestinationEndPoint(int ifIndex, int protocol, const uint8_t *destinationMacAddress);

private:
boost::shared_ptr<raw_protocol_t::socket> m_socketPtr;
raw_endpoint_t *m_pDestinationEndpoint;
};
```

In the .cpp file:

```
MyClass::MyClass(/*parameters*/):
m_socketPtr(new raw_protocol_t::socket(IOWorker.get_service()) //in my class constructor
{
//constructor body
m_socketPtr->open(raw_protocol_t(PF_PACKET, SOCK_DGRAM));

sockaddr_ll sockaddr;
memset(&sockaddr, 0, sizeof(sockaddr));
sockaddr.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
sockaddr.sll_protocol = htons(protocol);
sockaddr.sll_ifindex = ifIndex;

m_socketPtr->bind(raw_endpoint_t(&sockaddr, sizeof(sockaddr)));
}
//then User sets destination endpoint
void MyClass::SetDestinationEndPoint(int ifIndex, int protocol, const uint8_t *destinationMacAddress)
{
struct sockaddr_ll ll;
memset(&ll, 0, sizeof(ll));
ll.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
ll.sll_ifindex = ifIndex;
ll.sll_protocol = htons(protocol);
ll.sll_halen = ETH_ALEN;
memcpy(ll.sll_addr, destinationMacAddress, ETH_ALEN);
m_pDestinationEndpoint = new raw_endpoint_t(&ll, sizeof(ll), protocol);
}
```

Finally, a call to `async_send_to` is made to initiate sending of the payload:

```
m_socketPtr->async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(bufferPtr->GetBuffer().get(), bufferPtr->GetBufferSize()),
*m_pDestinationEndpoint,
boost::bind(/*params*/));
```

The buffer contains only the Ethernet payload and does not include the Ethernet header. As per my understanding, everything required to construct the Ethernet header is present in `*m_pDestinationEndpoint` (Set using the call to `SetDestinationEndPoint()`). However, I notice that just the payload is getting sent without the Ethernet header. What am I missing here? Secondly, is it necessary to use a separate destination endpoint, or can I use  `m_socketPtr->local_endpoint()` in the call to `async_send_to` (of course setting the destination MAC address in the constructor itself prior to calling `bind`)?

Comment: I might be wrong here, but `raw_protocol::socket` seems designed to specifically allow YOU to craft the packets. See also perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26212014/create-a-layer-2-ethernet-socket-with-boost-asio-raw-socket-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attaching `strace` to the process provided a hint:

```
strace  -e trace=network -p `pidof <process name>`
```

I expected to find

```
socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_DGRAM, 1)
```

But instead found

```
socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, 1)
```

which led me to believe the 2nd parameter to the `open` call of `socket` class does not specify socket type but protocol family

So I changed the protocol class from `raw_protocol` to `datagram_protocol` (and similar changes to endpoint classes) and it worked!

```
class MyClass
{
public:
MyClass(/*parameters*/);
typedef boost::asio::generic::datagram_protocol datagram_protocol_t;
typedef boost::asio::generic::basic_endpoint<datagram_protocol_t> datagram_endpoint_t;

void SetDestinationEndPoint(int ifIndex, int protocol, const uint8_t *destinationMacAddress);

private:
boost::shared_ptr<datagram_protocol_t::socket> m_socketPtr;
datagram_endpoint_t *m_pDestinationEndpoint;
};
```