# Check network link availability with Boost ASIO

Tags: networking, boost-asio, health-monitoring

Is there a simple way to detect network connection (like link light, not full internet connectivity), using Boost ASIO?

I would prefer to use boost for its cross platform capability and since I already have a dependency on it.

Comment: any updates over this ?

Comment: On Linux, you might use Netlink with asio as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13255447/af-netlink-netlink-sockets-using-boostasio .